# How to configure squid to be a Transparent proxy?

Tags: squid

I am working with Squid Proxy Server as I have also used cyberoam,Sonicwall and Clear OS.

I want to setup my own proxy like above products ie authentication in transparent proxy.
Actually  I setup transparent proxy but at that time my HTTPS site is not working.Then I configure one iptables rule that redirect all http & https traffic to 3128(squid port) only. but here I can access all my https  websites but I cant block them.

My requirement is when I am going to access any website at first time it will ask me to authentication and then and only i can access internet. In log reports also I can show its Username and one more thing it will also possible in thinclient(terminal service).

Anybody help me short-out this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Proxy authentication doesn't work in transparent proxies setups. The browser should have the proxy configured to catch the authentication request from a proxy and to request the credentials to an user.

Another thing is that you can create a transparent proxy for HTTPS. Why? Because when the browser connects, it's connected to the proxy, not the real server. The browser will try to negotiate SSL which is a thing that Squid won't support. There are tricks to do this, but you'll break the SSL security, browser will complain, etc. There are one tool that I used to get this working: [u2nl](http://www.reitwiessner.de/programs/u2nl.html), but it's a hack that tunnels HTTPS trought the proxy.

The best option, is to use a non-transparent proxy. If you want to avoid browsers configuration, have a look at [WPAD](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Technology/WPAD)

Answer (score 0):

As said before, you can't really block HTTPS sites with Squid, and you can't really use authentication with the proxy running at his transparent mode.

As far as I could use and cofigure, you can use an external acl to force a kind of login, but the login requests will not be treated by the proxy, but you can work it with some PERL.

And about the HTTPS thing, you could work it with some hacks, but it is a very sensible question, because the server performance with be punished with this kind of use and you could be pointed as a fraudulent service, which isn't cool... Believe me.